# Is SSMS .ssmssqlproj schema documented anywhere?

Tags: ssms

I've recently looked into a .ssmssqlproj file.
After quick trial/error it turned out, that Name attribute has no effect on the GUI. (btw it renamed after save, so after adding a 4th logical folder to the existing default three, there will be a duplicated in the project file.

```
<LogicalFolder Name="MiscellaneousTest" Type="3" Sorted="true">
  <Items />
</LogicalFolder>
```

I am trying to give a logical structure within one project, instead of having the 1000 files in a flat structure.

**Question**

After this "interesting" behaviour, I would take a look to the XML schema of the .ssmssqlproj file.
Googled, and not found maybe I am missing something.

Comment: As far as I can see from a "brief" look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/solution/files-that-manage-solutions-and-projects?view=sql-server-ver15#management-studio-project-files), no (not officially).

Comment: Sad. It's a shame btw how sloppy way it is parsed an interpreted on the GUI, reminds me a journeyman's work back in 1980 Commodore 64, it's 2021 for God's sake.